# what is the rank of a strictly diagonally dominant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

what is the rank of a strictly diagonally dominant matrix?explain.

---

Can someone help me please?I have no idea how to crack it.

Comment: tomorrow is my exam and I was solving the last year question paper.this is a question from that paper.

Comment: Might be related to Gershgorin's circle theorem. How diagonally dominant?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem. Whoops, looks like we have http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix

Comment: @Ataraxia: your examples are not diagonally dominant, because $1 < 2$.

Answer (score 2):

As Evan said, it is related to the Gershgorin circle theorem. The matrix is nonsingular.  Gershgorin says all eigenvalues are in the union of the disks centred at the diagonal elements $a_ii$ with radii 
$\sum_{j \ne i} |a_{ij}|$. Strictly diagonally dominant says that radius is less than $|a_{ii}|$, so the disk does not contain $0$.